# Creating app which opens a custom file extension

Tags: android, file

Want to create an android application, which opens a custom-build file extension (for example, I want to open .abcd files)

It is something like Adobe Reader that opens .pdf files, or Photo Viewer that opens .jpg files

*Specific conditions:*
1. The .abcd file should be outside / external from the application itself. (as .pdf is to Adobe Reader)
2. The .abcd file would be a zipped file, which contains few folders and .xml, .txt, and .jpg files. I think I want to extract it - maybe temporarily - to somewhere in the storage (definitely need a zipper/unzipper library), then read the individual .xml, .txt, and .jpg files.

**Looking for insights and answers for this problem.**

*Additional information:*
I am relatively new to Android programming.

Comment: To get your application to be invoked when someone taps on a .abcd file in the file explorer:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3760276/android-intent-filter-associate-app-with-file-extension/12915288#12915288 Once you are called, you can parse the file yourself. Java offers facilities to unzip files: java.util.ZipFile.

Comment: @EmmanuelTouzery +1, thank you very much. If doing so, will the file be passed into an argument to the application ?

Comment: It doesn't work like that, there is no main on android -- you'll receive an Intent and you can then handle it. Check out: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html

Comment: @RishabhSrivastava I'm still working on this project. I've found a way to unzip files from external storage (I forgot the link, but can be found with a simple google search).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think you need to do that type of customization via `intent-filter` something like:

```
<intent-filter android:icon="your_drawable-resource"
               android:label="your_string_resource"
               android:priority="integer"> 
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:scheme="file" />
    <data android:host="*" />
    <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.YOUR_CUSTOM_FILE_EXTENSION" />
</intent-filter>
```

Also you should look:

- [Custom Filetype in Android not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4675257/custom-filetype-in-android-not-working)
- [Android intent filter for a particular file extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1733195/android-intent-filter-for-a-particular-file-extension)
- [android intent filter for custom file extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14256537/android-intent-filter-for-custom-file-extension)

Answer (score 4):

One possible answer is shown 
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55976817/3453836)
. Try some customisation for intent filters.

```
<intent-filter android:priority="999">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.OPENABLE" />

    <data android:host="*" />
    <data android:mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
    <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\.yourextension" />
    <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\.yourextension" />
    <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\..*\\.yourextension" />
    <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\.yourextension" />
    <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.yourextension" />
    <data android:scheme="content" />
</intent-filter>
```