# android download manager open file with my application

Tags: android, android-download-manager

I have my android app, that downloads a file via the DownloadService. This file is in special file format, that only can be used in my app - it has the suffix *.foobar.

I start the download this way:

```
DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));
request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir("/", "aaaa.foobar");

// get download service and enqueue file
DownloadManager manager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
```

Download works fine, but when I tap on the notification "download finished", I want that my activity will be opened. What I get is the toast "File can not be opened".

In my Manifest I have a intent-filter for the .foobar file suffix.

```
    <intent-filter android:label="@string/app_name">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="file" />
        <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
        <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.foobar" />
        <data android:host="*" />
    </intent-filter>
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

finally found the solution!

I had to remove the path pattern line

```
                <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.foobar" />
```

and change the schema to content. So the complete intent filter is:

```
<intent-filter android:label="@string/app_name">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="content" />
                <data android:mimeType="application/wcmap" />
                <data android:host="*" />
            </intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you will find the answer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4683303/2413972). Most likely you have a problem in the treatment of Activiti or slightly incorrect description of intent.

Try [adding a priority](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18578704/2413972).

```
android:priority="integer"
```

Also you should look:

- [Android intent filter for a particular file extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1733195/android-intent-filter-for-a-particular-file-extension)
- [Android intent filter for custom file extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14256537/android-intent-filter-for-custom-file-extension)

Good luck. Sorry that can not help more. Too much text for a comment.